# Installing Apache OpenWhisk using docker-compose on Amazon Linux instance gets stuck at "waiting for the Whisk invoker to come up..."

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, openwhisk, amazon-linux

I am trying to install openwhisk for dev mode using docker compose on Amazon Linux EC2 Instance. I am following this link for doing so https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk -> Get Started.
Although, it has worked for me before once, in this installation, I am facing an issue. These are the steps I followed:

```
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum install -y docker

sudo service docker start

sudo chkconfig docker on

sudo yum install -y python-pip

sudo pip install docker-compose
```

This step is because open whisk is using sudo for docker-compose, and based on previous steps, sudo docker-compose -v gives a command not found.

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /bin

sudo yum install -y git

cd ~

git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-devtools.git

cd incubator-openwhisk-devtools/docker-compose

sudo make quick-start
```

**Update**: The problem is that the make command gets stuck at the stage where it is waiting for invokers.

I have not made any changes to any source code, nor I did any other steps before this on the instance. It was a freshly created instance.

Am I missing something in OpenWhisk or EC2 or the combination of both? Any help would be great.

**Update**: I tried the docker-compose method for installing open whisk on Amazon Linux 1, Amazon Linux 2, Ubuntu 16.04 as well as Ubuntu 14.04. On all platforms, it got stuck at sudo make quick-start where it is waiting for invokers.

**Update**: Instead of using python-pip for docker-compose installation, used the command from docker website as well.

sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 2):

if docker-compose command is not found it means you didn't install docker-compose correctly.
I don't think you can install docker-compose as a python library using pip

See the instructions here https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose

someting like

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Or take a look at https://medium.com/@khandelwal12nidhi/docker-setup-on-aws-ec2-instance-c670ff3d5f1b

Comment: Hi @csantanapr

Thanks for the reply.
docker-compose command not found is not the main issue. As I have mentioned, the next step basically solves that issue, i.e. moving docker-compose from /usr/local/bin -> /bin.

And docker-compose can be installed using python-pip. Here is the link: https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-centos-7/

Comment: You never posted what's the actually problem or error string your getting, how far the make command makes it?

Comment: Oh crap, I see it now. Sorry for the inconvenience. The make command is stuck at waiting for Listeners... I have updated the question as well.